# Qt Can't use OCR Tesseract with OpenCV 3.2 Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, shared-libraries, ocr

I am trying to use `cv::text::OCRTesseract` module but I get error:

```
undefined reference to `cv::text::OCRTesseract::create(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, int)'
```

I installed Tesseract and tested it from command line.

Here how my `ocr.hpp` file looks like:

[image]

The red line tells `unexpected token 'create'`

Is there any missing library or unlinked library or something else?

I didn't find a valid solution, please help!

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough to just include a header file of a library, you also need to link your app to the library. I have no experience with OpenCV and Tesseract, but it sounds like you need to add a reference to both libraries.

If you use Qt Creator, you can find out how to do this in [this manual page](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html).